# How to get a specific max value when there are ties in Ruby

Tags: ruby, max

I just started learning Ruby a few weeks ago so I apologize for being a complete noob. I am writing a simple program that will find the largest phone number input based on the sum of its digits. Here is what I have so far:

```
print 'Enter phone numbers'
phone_numbers = (gets.chomp)
phone_array = phone_numbers.split(",")

values = Hash.new(0)

phone_array.each { |x| values[x] += x.delete('-').to_s.split('').map(&:to_i).inject(:+)}

values.each { |k, v| puts k if v == values.values.max }
```

My question is: how do I get ruby to give me the phone number corresponding to a specific max value if there are equal max values? I would like the tie-breaking strategy to be last max value encountered. for example if I enter 111-111-1112,111-111-1121 I would like the output to be 111-111-1121.

Comment: You need to specify a tie-breaking strategy.  First one encountered?  Last one encountered?  Something else entirely?  Without that info folks here can give you arbitrary choices.

Comment: In general, you should not change the question when editing. Your edit contained a minor change. If you do that (as opposed to merely clarifying) you should note it as an edit (e.g., "Edit: ...."). In future, consider waiting awhile (a couple of hours anyway) before selecting an answer. There's no rush--just don't forget. A quick selection can discourage other, possibly better, answers, and is not appreciated by those still preparing answers.

Comment: Note you could write: `values = phone_array.each_with_object({}) { |x,h| h[x] = x.split|(/-|/).inject(0) { |t,c| t+c.to_i }`. The regex I used with `split` is rather cool, something I just discovered. It says to split on `-` or  `''` (empty string). Note that `split('')` also works, since `"-".to_i #=> 0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you only want one phone number (with the max value), `break` when one is found:

```
max_value = values.values.max   #store the max value to prevent computing it multiple times
values.each { |k, v| puts k; break if v == max_value }
#                            ^^^^^
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. what if I wanted the second/last max value? Is there a way to get that?

Comment: @noobcoder Sure. Use a variable to store the last seen key that has the max value. Print it after the block. Something like: `last = nil` 
`values.each { |k, v| last = k if v == values.values.max }` 
`puts last`

Comment: Are you sure you want to compute `values.values.max` for each element of `values` until a `max` is reached? (I know the OP was doing that.)

Answer (score 0):

```
phone_array.max_by { |phone_number| phone_number.scan(/\d/).map(&:to_i).reduce(:+) }
```

will return the phone number from which the sum of the digits are maxed.

If there are ties, the first item should be returned.

Answer (score 0):

This solution returns an array containing the maximum sum of digits and an array of all phone numbers whose sum of digits equals the maximum (in the order in which they appear in the string):

```
str = " 111-111-1112, 111-111-1111,111-111-1121"

str.gsub(/\s/,'').
    split(/\s*,\s*/).
    each_with_object(Hash.new { |h,k| h[k]=[] }) do |s,h|
      h[s.each_char.reduce(0) { |t,c| t+c.to_i }] << s
    end.
    max_by(&:last)
  #=> [11, ["111-111-1112", "111-111-1121"]]
```

Note that `'-'.to_i #=> 0`.